# Floating point comparison.

Tags: python, floating-point, comparison

There is a better way to write this code:

```
for i in range(50, 56, 1):
        print(i / 10)
print("Half way done!")
for k in range(56, 61, 1):
     print(k / 10)
print("All the way done!")
```

Output:

```
5.0
5.1
5.2
5.3
5.4
5.5
Half way done!
5.6
5.7
5.8
5.9
6.0
All the way done!
```

I've been trying to compare floating point numbers and this is the best I have gotten so far, there are methods out there but I cant understand them as I'm not at that level yet, so if anyone could provide an alternative way of comparing floating point numbers, that would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You're not actually performing any floating-point comparison here. What are you trying to learn? Do you want to learn something about comparing floating-point numbers? Or do you want to learn something about performing an action halfway through a loop?

Comment: I'm trying to learn an action halfway through a loop, by comparing floating point numbers, I could have word my question better! the output needs to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to compare `i/10` to `5.5`, simply compare the loop iterator (which is an integer) to the calculated halfway point (another integer):

```
start = 50
end = 61
half = (end-start)//2 + start
for i in range(50, 61):
    print(i/10)
    if i == half:
        print('Half way done!')

print("All the way done!")
```

Comment: this got me thinking, is there a way for me to do something along the lines of adding a 0.1 to 50 making it 50.1 and giving the same output?

Comment: @Adem - I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: taking floating point numbers from the start and instead of "/" the value, making it so it adds the value "0.1" to say 50 so result= 50.1 and repeats this process from start till end, giving the same output

Comment: @Adem - You could do `i = 5` and then `for i in range(10): i += 0.1` with `print(i)` and an `if math.isclose(i, 5.5): print('Half way done!')` (note that `math.isclose` is available starting in Python 3.5). There are several ways to accomplish this.

Comment: I'm however using python 3.4, in which I cant seem to do math.isclose

Comment: @Adem - Sticking with integer comparison is probably your best bet, then.